# Is it possible to have a url parameter with a constant value through out the ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and trying to learn new things while playing around with the following scenario, but didn't get it working.

Actually, I am trying to maintain a constant value parameter in the url for every request. Something similar when we have a session value in the url, after using `<sessionState cookieless="true"/>` in Web.config file and it starts showing session value in this format

http://localhost:49961/(S(swl0ancynhWw2103jxm4ydwf))/Customer/Home

But I am trying to have a persistent parameter appended at the end of url for every request, like following link

http://localhost:49961/Customer/Home?constantVal=12345

This parameter is assumed to remain in url, whether I am using any `HttpGet` or `HttpPost` method.

So far I have tried re-writing the url using `Application_BeginRequest()` inside Global.asax.cs file in following way:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Suppose Request.FilePath = /Customer/Home/UploadFile
    // Unable to use "?constantVal" as required
    Context.RewritePath(Request.FilePath + "/12345");
}
```

**Action Method:**

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(string id = null)
{
    return View();
}
```

In the above way, although I am able to get value for id = "12345" in **UploadFile** Action, but neither it is showing in the url anywhere or it also require every `HttpGet` method to have a receiving **id** parameter.

*It's always nice to do something crazy so that you can better understand a system.*   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a url parameter with a constant value through out the ASP.NET MVC application?

Yes.

However, your example (`http://localhost:49961/Customer/Home?constantVal=12345`) will not work because the `Route` class *completely ignores* query string values. It is possible to [extend routing to make it query string aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38161230/181087), though.

By default, route values are [automatically reused from the current request](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1346), so if you put a value there, it will just "stick" from one request to the next if all of the URLs on the site are built with the `UrlHelper` (or function that uses the `UrlHelper`, such as `ActionLink`). See [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32839796/181087) for an example of putting the culture into the URL, which preserves it between requests automatically.

That said, using `RewritePath` in this context doesn't make any sense. `RewritePath` changes the *URL that the HTTP handler sees*, not the URL in the browser that the user sees. In fact, since we have routing to map a request *directly* to a controller action, using `RewritePath` in MVC really doesn't make sense at all. To change the URL that the user sees, you need to do a 302 or 301 redirect. See [How to change route to username after logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37022067/181087) for an example of redirecting to add a value to the URL automatically under a specific condition, which is similar to your use case.

Comment: Thanks @NightOwl888, for showing the right path to move on. You are everywhere in links.. Keep sharing your knowledge :)